# Recurrence Equations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can someone explain how that Tn = 2Tn-1 + 1 sequence actually works?

Comment: Ok, that part I get... So in the T1 = 2, how did the sequence go from 2, 5, 11... Shouldn't there be a 7 in there if I plugged in 3 into the equation? Or in the Ti = -1, why is the sequence all -1?

Thank you much

Comment: If $T_1 = 2$, then $T_2 = 2 * (T_1) + 1 = 2 * 2 + 1 = 5$ the recurrence derivation goes on to get 11.....For n = 3, you are looking at $T_3 = 2 * T_2 + 1 = 2 * 5 + 1 = 11$, but not 7.

Answer (score 2):

The subscript merely indicates which term of the sequence we are using. Thus, $T_n$ represents the value of the nth term of the sequence.  The above interpretation applies equally well to any other term (eg. $n - 1$).

$T_n = 2T_{n-1} + 1$ means "to find the value of the nth term of the sequence, you need to find the value of $(n - 1)$th term first; then 2 times it; and then add 1 to it".

Answer (score 1):

The recurrence sequence is a sequence that each term is defined by its previous terms. Hence, the sequence must have the initial term. For example,

$T_n=2T_{n-1}+1.$ Assume that the sequence begin at $T_1.$

So, $T_2=2T_1+1$,

$T_3=2T_2+1=2(2T_1+1)+1=4T_1+3$ and so on.

We can see that if we do not know the value of $T_1$, we also can not find the value 
of $ T_2,T_3,...$

In fact, we can define recurrence relation that T_n is defined by T_{n-2}. For example,

$T_n=T_{n-2}+1$.

But in this case, the initial values must have 2 terms(T_1 and T_2).

If you want to find $T_{1000}$ of a recurrence sequence, you have to find $T_{999},T_{998},...$. It is not difficult, but it takes so much time. So, how can we find $T_{1000}$ without finding $T_{999}, T_{998},...$? That is the goal of recurrence equation.

Comment: Denote that General form or solution of recurrence sequence means $T_n$ is directly defined by only $n$ not from the previous term.

In fact, you can find a general form only some recurrence sequence. For example,

$T_n=T_{n-1} +1$ such that $T_1=1.$

You can easily see that $T_n=n$ is the solution or general form of the above sequence.

Comment: If a recurrence sequence is complicated, it is also difficult to find a general solution for it. I thinks in that book will teach you methods for finding a general solution of some specific recurrence sequences.

Comment: Nevermind all... Got it... Rest will do wonders for a person LOL... Was just brain dead last night... Now it's clear...

Comment: @WorawitTepsan How would we find out the recurrence equation in this case?

Answer (score 0):

A recurrence relation is a rule for generating a sequence of numbers (loosely). So let's say I give you a number, for instance $0$ and a rule: *double your number and add 1*. If you apply the rule repeatedly (starting with zero), you will get a sequence: $$(0,1,3,7,15,31,63,127...$$

More formally, we could say that $T_n$ is the $n$-th number in the sequence, starting from $n=0$. So for example, $T_0=0$, $T_1=1$ and $T_5=31$. Then the rule *double your number and add 1* becomes: $$T_n=2T_{n-1}+1$$

Does this help?

Comment: So $n$ (what we call the *subscript*) denotes the position in the sequence above. $T_0$ represents the first number,0. $T_1$ represents the second and so on. So $T_5$ means *start from the first number in the sequence, and move to the right 5 times*. So $T_{2}=3,T_{3}=7,T_{4}=15$ and so on.

Comment: You definitely are plugging numbers in. The recurrence relation tells you how to get the next number in the sequence. So we know from above that $T_8=127$. We want to get the next number in the sequence. So here we take $n-1$ to be 8. So $n=(n-1)+1=9$. Plugging in these values into the recurrence relation: $T_9=2(T_{8})+1=2(127)+1=257.

Comment: Is there any way to compute $T_{n}$ without computing the sequence before? Just curious.